# grails gorm mongodb `like` functionality in criteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm, gorm-mongodb

Is `like` or `rlike` supported for searching a string in a collection's property value? 
Does the collection need to define text type index for this to work? Unfortunately I can not create a text index for the property. There are 100 million documents and text index killed the performance (MongoDB is on single node). 
If this is not do-able without text index, its fine with me. I will look for alternatives.

Given below collection:

```
Message {
    'payload' : 'XML or JSON string' 
    //few other properties
}
```

In grails, I created a Criteria to return me a list of documents which contain a specific string in the payload

```
Message.list {
  projections {
    like('payload' : searchString)
  }
}
```

I tried using `rlike('payload' : ".*${searchString}.*")` as well. It did not result in any doc to me.

**Note**: I was able to get the document when I fired the native query on Mongo shell.

```
db.Message.find({payload : { $regex : ".*My search string.*" }}).pretty()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working in a round about way. I believe there is a much better grails solution. Criteria approach did not work. So used the low level API converted the DBObjects to Domain objects.

```
        def query = ['payload' : [ '$regex' : /${searchString}/ ]  ]
        def dbObjects = Message.collection.find(query).skip(offset).limit(defaultPageSize).toArray()
        dbObjects?.collect { new Message(new JsonSlurper().parseText(it.toString()))}
```